# replacing multiple strings in a column with a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column named "New_category" and I have to replace multiple strings into the column with the word "brandies". I have created the following list:

```
brandies = ["apricot brandies", "cherry brandies", "peach brandies"]
```

I want to write a formula, which will replace "apricot brandies", "cherry brandies", "peach brandies" in the column with the word "brandies".

This is what i have tried but it does not work.

```
iowa['New_category'] = iowa['New_Category'].str.replace('brandies','Brandies')
```

Comment: Is this using a `pandas` dataframe or just vanilla python?

Comment: i am using pandas dataframe

Comment: Do you have a column of lists? or is it a column of one string per intersection of row and column?

Answer (score 0):

When using `str.replace` use a pattern that captures the whole string.

```
iowa['New_category'] = iowa['New_category'].str.replace('^.*brandies.*$', 'Brandies')
```

Comment: I tried this code but it's not giving me the desired result. Apricot brandies, cherry and peach brandies are still appearing

Comment: @OmerQureshi you have to assign the results back to the column.  I only showed the evaluation part.  I'll update post

Comment: The values are still the same. It hasn't changed

Comment: are you sure that string code str isn't a problem as we are extracting the value from list

Comment: @OmerQureshi Its clear to me that you've inadequately described your problem.  Do yourself a favor and edit your question ***showing*** what your data looks like and ***showing*** what you expect to have as output.